# Compare each string with all other strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, vectorization, similarity

I have this dataframe:

```
mylist = [
    "₹67.00 to Rupam Sweets using Bank Account XXXXXXXX5343<br>11 Feb 2023, 20:42:25",
    "₹66.00 to Rupam Sweets using Bank Account XXXXXXXX5343<br>10 Feb 2023, 21:09:23",
    "₹32.00 to Nagori Sajjad Mohammed Sayyed using Bank Account XXXXXXXX5343<br>9 Feb 2023, 07:06:52",
    "₹110.00 to Vikram Manohar Jsohi using Bank Account XXXXXXXX5343<br>9 Feb 2023, 06:40:08",
    "₹120.00 to Winner Dinesh Gupta using Bank Account XXXXXXXX5343<br>30 Jan 2023, 06:23:55",
]
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.columns = ["full_text"]
ndf = df.full_text.str.split("to", expand=True)
ndf.columns = ["amt", "full_text"]
ndf2 = ndf.full_text.str.split("using Bank Account XXXXXXXX5343<br>", expand=True)
ndf2.columns = ["client", "date"]
df = ndf.join(ndf2)[["date", "client", "amt"]]
```

I have created embeddings for each client name:

```
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding, cosine_similarity
import openai

openai.api_key = 'xxx'
embedding_model = "text-embedding-ada-002"
embeddings = df.client.apply([lambda x: get_embedding(x, engine=embedding_model)])
df["embeddings"] = embeddings
```

I can now calculate the similarity index for a given string. For e.g. "Rupam Sweet" using:

```
query_embedding = get_embedding("Rupam Sweet", engine="text-embedding-ada-002")
df["similarity"] = df.embeddings.apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, query_embedding))
```

But I need the similarity score of each client across all other clients. In other words, the client names will be in rows as well as in columns and the score will be the data. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a vectorized similarity function `f(x, y)` and want to apply it to all pairs of a series, you can make use of numpy broadcasting. If `f` is not a vectorized function, you can turn it into one by calling `f_vec = np.vectorize(f)` on it. In the example below, I'm using the `ratio` function from the `fuzzywuzzy` module for illustration purposes, but it works the same way with any other comparison function.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy.fuzz import ratio
import numpy as np

ratio_vec = np.vectorize(ratio)
s = pd.Series(mylist)
df = pd.DataFrame(ratio_vec(s, s[:, None]))
```

The result is a similarity matrix:

```py
     0    1    2    3    4
0  100   92   74   76   71
1   92  100   74   73   72
2   70   74  100   74   67
3   73   73   73  100   72
4   71   72   64   74  100
```

Comment: Upvoted and bounty will be awarded even if this is not exact solution that I was looking for. I have already tried most of the fuzzy match modules and found that they are not suitable in this use case. For e.g. the embeddings comparison suggested this match.
'AADARSH HIGH SCHOOL MANDAL', 'AADARSHA VIDYA. MAR.HIGHSCHOOL' fuzz.ratio missed it.

Comment: I guess you are not suggesting to use fuzzy module but to use numpy vectorization. Let me try it and get back.

Comment: I had never thought of subclassing a function like this. This is awesome! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for the bounty! Right, I was just using `fuzzywuzzy.ratio` as an example of a two-placed distance function. It should work exactly the same with the `cosine_similarity` from the openai module (in fact, the function might already be vectorized so you might be able to skip the `np.vectorize` step, but I'm not sure since I never worked with it).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the expected results using:

```
for k, i in enumerate(df.client):
    query_embedding = get_embedding(i, engine="text-embedding-ada-002")
    df[i + str(k)] = df.embeddings.apply(
        lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, query_embedding)
    )
```

I am not sure if this is efficient in case of big data.